# Screen turns blank while installing Ubuntu 12.04 from a DVD

Tags: 12.04, installation, livedvd

When I try to install Ubuntu 12.04 by DVD, I insert the DVD and select the booting option as DVD. Next I press the enter key to install. After few seconds my screen goes blank like when the computer is turned off.

During this blank screen there are quiet sounds of disk writing for about 15 to 20 minutes from the DVD writer, after this the sound stops. My computer is on but the screen remains blank.

Please help me install Ubuntu on my system.

My system configuration is--

- Hp pavilion g4
- RAM 4 GB
- Hard disk 640 GB
- Processor Intel i5
- operating system is Windows 7 home basic 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is problem with DVD.  Try using pendrive/USB for installation or try to install on some other computer with same DVD to confirm that DVD is working properly.